# Error logging in Windows CE C#

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I'm writing a Windows CE App and want to implement error logging to a .txt file.

I've done research and saw this example:

```
public static void Logs(string fileName, string methodName, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                using (FileStream file = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\\Log.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(file);
                    streamWriter.WriteLine((((System.DateTime.Now + " - ") + fileName + " - ") + methodName + " - ") + message);
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    } 

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int a = 10, b = 0;
            int result = a / b; //runtime Exception will throw
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logs(this.GetType().Name, "button1_Click()", ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

That works but only in Windows Forms. I'm getting this error in Windows CE:

```
'System.Windows.Application' does not contain a definition for 'StartupPath'
```

Ok, so I know I have to use this:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ().GetName ().CodeBase);
```

But I'm not sure how. Still learning so please don't mark this as duplicate. Can someone rather just explain to me exactly where and how to use this in Windows CE app?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function that returns the path of the executing assembly... just like:

```
public static string GetCurrentApplicationPath() 
{
  return System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
}
```

and use this function in place of `Application.StartupPath`

Comment: @Werner Remove the `=` from the statement.

Comment: Ok, So I don't get any errors when I debug, but Log.txt doesn't get created like it did in the Windows Form?

Comment: Are you sure the path you're writing log to is correct?
Maybe 'Logs' function throws an exception but you're catching it without displaying any error. Try to debug your code and see if you reach the catch block..

Comment: Debugged and Logs Function does not trow any exceptions. Not sure about the path though. What the previous code did (i think) was to write the log.txt in the start path of the app, hence the `Application.StartupPath`. Am I correct? I didn't think i would need to add a path? I thought that the `GetCurrentApplicationPath` will do it?

Comment: GetCurrentApplicationPath returns for example \MyCompany\MyProduct, so you have to add the file name.